# method to find my UDP socket's "real" port?

Tags: sockets, udp, p2p, nat

Is there any free service to which I could send a UDP packet and it would respond telling me what is my "real" UDP port? (my application is behind a NAT)

This kind of service could allow me to [make a p2p coordination server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164656/p2p-network-games-apps-good-choice-for-a-battle-net-like-matching-server) with normal php hosting.

- The p2p clients would know their UDP ports from this service
- They will then contact my server over HTTP (which is what regular web hosting allows) and tell it their port (and ip, which is normally supplied to cgi scripts)
- My server will give the clients the IP addresses and ports of the other clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such service is called STUN. If you query a search engine for public stun server you should get a bunch of results. There is an [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389) on STUN servers, but I would be surprised if any public server would conform to that.

Comment: @Zed: awesome! seems like there are several public servers for STUN. see list in http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/STUN